# Font conversion sources

Tags: php, fonts

Have a question - you see a lot of free font conversion tools online. Since those are free, I assume that technology behind them is not top secret/patented/commercial use only.

I need to convert fonts on the fly in my application (using PHP).

Can anyone point me to some resources on how I can build my own font converter (where to get those backed scripts to convert font types).

Comment: Have you tried Cufon? http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: Hi, this is not what I am looking for, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I have found that I can use [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)  application to convert font files from console command line.

Thanks to that I can write PHP script to convert fonts as per my requirement with help of [Font Forge scripts](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/scripting-tutorial.html).

Hope someone will find it usefull.

Comment: You create a PHP script to do this??

Comment: Yes, because I need it in a PHP backed application.

Comment: Can you share with me?