# PHP Web font kit generator

Tags: webfonts

Does anyone know if there is anything around that can take an uploaded font file and automatically convert it for use as a web font?

I know there are legal issues around this, but places like Font Squirrel seem to manage, I have a private network of users and I'd really like to provide them with the opportunity to upload the fonts they use for their brand and the advice they need to use those fonts legally on line.

Online services like Font Squirrel are not really an option because my users are non-tech users and won't understand that service- they just can't understand why they cant use the fonts they want, when they can use them in Word documents, pdf's and images etc. They just want to use them basically. What I can do is automate the upload and creation and payment where necessary, and from the users point of view they can just upload the font they want to use, get billed for it and start using it.

So yeah does anyone know of anything PHP that would help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After some more searching I found something that may be of help in the last post on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396047/font-conversion-sources, quite a bit more onerous that I was hoping for though, anything new out there?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [this](http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-woff). That’s a simple on-the-fly OTF to WOFF converter which does not require registration.